# Trying to create variables from elements in a list

Tags: python, list, element

this is my second time trying to ask this question, hoping it comes across more concise this time round.

I have a list of batsmen for a cricket score calculator I am trying to get up and running.
eg.

```
    batsmen = ['S Ganguly', 'M Brown', 'R Uthappa', 'A Majumdar', 'S Smith', 'A Mathews', 'M Manhas', 'W Parnell', 'B Kumar', 'M Kartik', 'A Nehra']
```

With this list I have a for loop that I run through currently without the list, it just works to calculate 2 teams and finds a winner.

```
    for overs in range(overlimit):
       for balls in range(6):
          balls_team = balls_team+ 1
          runtotal_team = input('Enter runs: ')
```

I am trying to utilise the list as a means of keeping score as well as holding values for each of the batsmen.

I'm hoping one of you guys can help. I'm assuming a while loop can be used but I am unable to figure out how to implement the list..

Answer (score 4):

Dictionary?

```
batsmenDict = {
 'A Majumdar': 0,
 'A Mathews': 0,
 'A Nehra': 0,
 'B Kumar': 0,
 'M Brown': 0,
 'M Kartik': 0,
 'M Manhas': 0,
 'R Uthappa': 0,
 'S Ganguly': 0,
 'S Smith': 0,
 'W Parnell': 0}

batsmenDict['M Manhas'] += 1
```

There is even a special collection type called a defaultdict that would let you make the default value 0 for each player:

```
from collections import defaultdict

batsmenDict = defaultdict(int)
print batsmenDict['R Uthappa']
# 0
batsmenDict['R Uthappa'] +=1 
print batsmenDict['R Uthappa']
# 1
```

Comment: +1 for defaultdict. And i just want to mention the alternative `dict.setdefault(key, default)`

Comment: @ch3ka: Thanks. And yea there is that method, though you have to do a little more manual work for each key.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict), then the names of the batsmen can become the keys for the dict, and their runs/scores the value.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary

```
>>> batsmen = [ ... ]
>>> d = dict.fromkeys(batsmen)
>>> d['A Mathews'] = 14
>>> d['A Mathews']
14
```

Comment: That gives you an initial dict with `None` values. `dict.fromkeys(batsmen, 0)` might be more useful as the initial values are all 0